# Clean exit when killing a PHP cron

Tags: php, transactions, cron, kill

I'm running several PHP cron jobs, which are running *transactional* updates on the disk. By *transactional*, I mean that several updates to the filesystem need to be either **all committed together** to the filesystem, or **none committed**, same concept as for a database transaction.

I have no technical way to enforce this filesystem *transaction* (any pointer would be appreciated on this point though), so I rely on my PHP cron job to properly group these updates.

However, sometimes I need to kill a long-running cron job (with Control-C), and I'd like to break my script at a safe breakpoint.

When programming for a web application, I use a combination of [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and 
[connection_aborted()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php), so I'm looking for the same kind of solution for command-line applications:

Is it possible to catch the `kill` signal, and to exit only when a safe point is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php